# Dash is empty, applications do not appear

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, dash-shell

I use Unity on Ubuntu 14.04. In Dash, applications are not present.

Folders&files and plugins are there though.

I tried :

```
unity --reset
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
```

and didn't worked.

How can I get the Dash working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked with `unity --replace`.

Comment: This really worked!